# Issues with searching for specific phrases within a column in R [First Question Ever]

Tags: r, if-statement

I hope everyone is doing well. I would like to preface this post by pointing out that I am very new to using R, and entirely new to the Stack Overflow community here.

I will try to follow the guidelines for posting to the best of my ability, and I apologize in advance if my question is unclear in any way.

I recently collected survey data pertaining to the recruitment trends for student-led organizations at my business school. I have collected this data using a google form, which I then exported to a CSV file and read into R.

---

One particular column of data "Application.Awareness" shows student responses for how they became aware of recruitment events. Responses include character strings such as "Word of Mouth" , "Email", and "Social Media".

Students may select more than one option when answering, so many of my rows look like:

*Word of Mouth, Social Media*

*Social Media, Email, Word of Mouth*

*Word of Mouth*

*Social Media, Email*

*Email*

---

**My Issue**

I want to create separate columns for Social Media, Word of Mouth, and Email, so that I can easily measure and compare the popularity of these three options.

To do so, I have tried to utilize the IfElse arugment, which I thought would mark rows that contain "Email" with a "1".

`MyData$App.Awareness.Email <- ifelse(MyData$Application.Awareness == "Email",1,0)`

However, this code only works for rows of data which ONLY contain the response "Email".
For example, a response containing "Email, Social Media" will result in a "0" in the new column.

**My Question**

Based on the problem above, is there a way to pull the observations that **contain** the word "Email", even if there are other words/phrases in the same row?

I hope I am articulating this well, please let me know if you need me to explain further. Thank you to anyone who has taken the time to read this!

Comment: Check out `grepl` rather than trying to test for equality with `==`, so `ifelse(grepl("Email", MyData$Application.Awareness),1,0)`

Comment: thank you, this was very helpful!